# Custom Azure Virtual Machine image

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I want to make a custom Virtual Machine image for the Azure cloud. When creating an new Azure cloud instance the Azure cloud should use *my* Virtual Machine image and not the standard Azure one. On my Virtual Machine image I want a database server installed, and the database should be able to access the physical drives for reasons of I/O performance. Is all this possible, and how should I proceed to achieve this?

Comment: "...a custom Azure cloud instance image for the Azure cloud." Are you talking about how to create a custom Virtual Machine image?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Yes, I will update the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do that.

You can start from an existing VM Azure image: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/

You can also upload a VHD: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-create-upload-vhd-windows-server/

Comment: Will the database get access to the physical harddisks or just some virtual (network) disks?

Comment: Everything is virtualized and you create data disks out of Azure storage.

Comment: I'm not sure what that entails, does this mean I only get access to network storage devices?

Comment: You don't have access to physical drives.  Here's how to create a data disk: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-windows-attach-disk/